# Django: Adding property to User model after creating model based on abstract class

Tags: django, generic-relations

I have a normal model and an abstract model like so:

```
class TaggedSubject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # etc

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    content_object_pk = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey("content_type", "content_object_pk")

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.user:
            return "%s" % (self.user.get_full_name() or self.user.username)
        else:
            return self.label

class Taggable(models.Model):
    tagged_subjects = generic.GenericRelation(TaggedSubject, content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='content_object_pk')

    @property
    def tagged_users(self):
        return User.objects.filter(pk__in=self.tagged_subjects.filter(user__isnull=False).values("user"))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

The `Taggable` abstract model class then gets used like so:

```
class Photo(Taggable):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="foo")
    # ... etc
```

So if we have a photo object:

```
photo = Photo.objects.all()[0]
```

I can all the users tagged in the photo with photo.tagged_users.all()

I want to add the inverse relation to the user object, so that if I have a user:

```
user = User.objects.filter(pk__in=TaggedSubject.objects.exclude(user__isnull=True).values("user"))[0]
```

I can call something like `user.tagged_photo_set.all()` and have it return all the photo objects.

I suspect that since TaggedSubject connects to the Taggable model on a generic relation that it won't be possible to use it as a `through` model with a `ManyToMany` field.

Assuming this is true, this is the function I believe I'd need to add (somehow) to the User model:

```
def tagged_photo_set(self):
    Photo.objects.filter(pk__in=TaggedSubject.objects.filter(user=self, content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Photo))
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to set it up so that each time a new model class is created based on Taggable, it creates a version of the function above and adds it (ideally as a function that behaves like a property!) to User.

Alternatively, if it *is* somehow possible to do ManyToMany field connections on a generic relation (which I highly doubt), that would work too.

Finally, if there is a third even cooler option that I am not seeing, I'm certainly open to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `add_to_class` and the `class_prepared` signal to do some post processing when models subclassing your base class are set up:

```
def add_to_user(sender, **kwargs):
    def tagged_FOO_set(self):
        return sender.objects.filter(pk__in=TaggedSubject.objects.filter(
            user=self,
            content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(sender)))

    if issubclass(sender, MyAbstractClass):
        method_name = 'tagged_{model}_set'.format(model=sender.__name__.lower())
        User.add_to_class(method_name, property(tagged_FOO_set))

class_prepared.connect(add_to_user)
```

Comment: Oh cool! I was able to get something like this working, only by subclassing ModelBase and adding it in the __new__ function, but your version is *much* cleaner!

Comment: @JordanReiter Thanks for the chance to check it out! I'm sure I'll use the pattern in the future :) I like how it keeps the abstract class prep in one location.